# Applying functions on columns in nested data frame

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I have data that I'm nesting into list columns, then I'd like to use purrr::map() to apply a plotting function separately to each column within the nested data frames. Minimal reproducible example:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

data=data.frame(Type=c(rep('Type1',20),
                       rep('Type2',20),
                       rep('Type3',20)),
                Result1=rnorm(60),
                Result2=rnorm(60),
                Result3=rnorm(60)
                )

dataNested=data%>%group_by(Type)%>%nest()
```

Say, I wanted to generate a histogram for Result1:Result3 for each element of dataNested$data:

```
dataNested%>%map(data,hist)
```

Any iteration of my code won't separately iterate over the columns within each nested dataframe.

Comment: What exactly does 'generate histogram for Result1:Result3' mean? One histogram of the concatenated data? Three histograms per `Type`?

Answer (score 2):

Why would you need to complicate things in such way, when you're already in the `tidyverse`? List columns are rather a last resort solution to problems..

```
library(tidyverse)

data %>%
  gather(result, value, -Type) %>%
  ggplot(aes(value)) + 
  geom_histogram() + 
  facet_grid(Type ~ result)
```

`gather` reformats the wide dataset into a long one, with `Type` column, `result` column and a `value` column, where all the numbers are.

Comment: My application is a lot bigger in scope in terms of data and what my outputs are. The complexity of purrr saves me a lot down the road in terms of outputs.

Comment: More complexity means keeping the data in a nice rectangular form is even more important;) Complex problems need simple solutions.

Comment: I need to compute values and feed those lists into my output as arguments, saving me from a ton of manual coding. That's what purrr is getting me.

Comment: I'm not arguing against `purrr`, I do use it often. Just if google brings here someone who's only trying to plot nine histograms, list columns are not the way to go.
If you specify more precisely what your desired output is, I can try to come up with a pure purrr answer @scs217.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps do not create a nested data frame. We can split the data frame by the `Type` column and plot the histogram.

```
library(tidyverse)

dt %>%
  split(.$Type) %>%
  map(~walk(.[-1], ~hist(.)))
```

**DATA**

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)

dt <- data.frame(Type = c(rep('Type1', 20),
                          rep('Type2', 20),
                          rep('Type3', 20)),
                 Result1 = rnorm(60),
                 Result2 = rnorm(60),
                 Result3 = rnorm(60),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Note that in order to display all 3x3 histograms, you'll need `op <- par(mfrow = c(3, 3))` and after the plot, `par(op)` to reset the graphics parameters.

Answer (score 1):

So I think you are thinking about this the right way. Running this code:

```
dataNested$data[[1]
```

You can see that you have data that you can iterate.  You can loop through it like:

```
for(i in dataNested) {
print(i)
}
```

This clearly demonstrates that the structure is nothing too complicated to work with. Okay so how to create the histograms? We can create a helper function:

```
helper_hist <- function(df) {
               lapply(df, hist)
}
```

And run using:

```
 map(dataNested$data, helper_hist)
```

Hope this helps.